# Filter the ListView Items without use of Button

Tags: android, json, listview, filter

I am able to Apply Filter to the ListView on the Data through WEB only when i Click on the Search Button. But i Want the data to be filtered when both EditText are filled without clicking on the Search button. I am using two editText:  startdate and endDate. when i click on the search button, filter is working but i want the data to be filtered irrespective of the order of entering the date in the editText.

**AttendanceStudentFragment**

```
public class AttendanceStudentFragment extends Fragment {


    ListView listView;
    String Navigation_URL = "http://192.168.100.5:84/api/academics/attendance";
    String Navigation_URL_FILTER = "http://192.168.100.5:84/api/academics/searchAttndByDate";
    String master_id, date, status, remarks;
    EditText editTextStartDate, editTextEndDate;
    Button buttonSearch;

    Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.student_attendance_listview, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);


        SessionManagement sessionManagement = new SessionManagement(getContext());
        master_id = sessionManagement.getMasterId();
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_student_attendance);

        editTextStartDate = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.student_attendance_startDate);
        editTextEndDate = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.student_attendance_endDate);
        buttonSearch = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.student_attendance_searchbutton);

        // editTextStartDate.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        // editTextStartDate.requestFocus();

        final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                updateLabelStartDate();
            }
        };

        final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date1 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                updateLabelEndDate();


            }
        };


        editTextStartDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), date, myCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            }
        });


        // collegeAdmissionStartDatePicker.show();


        editTextEndDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), date1, myCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();


            }
        });

        getAttendanceData();
        buttonSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                getAttendanceDataWithFilter();

            }
        });


        if(editTextEndDate.length()!=0 && editTextStartDate.length()!=0){

            getAttendanceDataWithFilter();
        }    


        return view;


    }

    private void updateLabelStartDate() {

        String myFormat = "MM/dd/yy"; //In which you need put here
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
        editTextStartDate.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));

        //editTextEndDate.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));

    }


    private void updateLabelEndDate() {

        String myFormat = "MM/dd/yy"; //In which you need put here
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
        // editTextStartDate.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
        editTextEndDate.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));

    }

    public void getAttendanceData() {


        String URL = Navigation_URL + "?StdID=" + master_id;
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {


                            ArrayList<StudentAttendancePojo> student_attendance_list = new ArrayList<>();
                            System.out.println(student_attendance_list.size());
                            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);

                            //  studentFeeInformation = new StudentFeeInformation(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                date = jsonObject.getString("DateOfAttendance").substring(0, 10);
                                status = jsonObject.getString("STATUS");
                                remarks = jsonObject.getString("Remarks");


                                //  student_list.add(new StudentFeeInformation(status, DateofReceiptIssued, ReceiptNumber, FeeReceivedDate));
                                //
                                //JSONArray jArray1 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Description");
                                StudentAttendancePojo studentAttendancePojo = new StudentAttendancePojo(date, status, remarks);


                                System.out.println("total lengthArray" + jArray.length());
                                student_attendance_list.add(studentAttendancePojo);


                            }

                            System.out.println("student_list size:" + student_attendance_list.size());
                            StudentAttendanceAdapter studentAttendanceAdapter = new StudentAttendanceAdapter(getActivity(), student_attendance_list);
                            System.out.println(student_attendance_list.size());
                            listView.setAdapter(studentAttendanceAdapter);


                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            System.out.println("This is not good");
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }

                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // Toast.makeText(view.Fee.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                return headers;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


    }


    public void getAttendanceDataWithFilter() {


        //  editTextStartDate.getText().toString();
        //  editTextEndDate.getText().toString();
        // String URL = Navigation_URL_FILTER + "?StdID=" + master_id + "&fromDate=" + "2017-06-01" + "&toDate=" + "2017-06-10";
        String URL = Navigation_URL_FILTER + "?StdID=" + master_id + "&fromDate=" + editTextStartDate.getText() + "&toDate=" + editTextEndDate.getText();
        //String URL = Navigation_URL + "?fromDate=" + editTextStartDate + "&toDate" + editTextEndDate + "StdID" + master_id;
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {


                            ArrayList<StudentAttendancePojo> student_attendance_list = new ArrayList<>();
                            System.out.println(student_attendance_list.size());
                            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);

                            //  studentFeeInformation = new StudentFeeInformation(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                date = jsonObject.getString("DateOfAttendance").substring(0, 10);
                                status = jsonObject.getString("STATUS");
                                remarks = jsonObject.getString("Remarks");


                                //  student_list.add(new StudentFeeInformation(status, DateofReceiptIssued, ReceiptNumber, FeeReceivedDate));
                                //
                                //JSONArray jArray1 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Description");
                                StudentAttendancePojo studentAttendancePojo = new StudentAttendancePojo(date, status, remarks);


                                System.out.println("total lengthArray" + jArray.length());
                                student_attendance_list.add(studentAttendancePojo);


                            }

                            System.out.println("student_list size:" + student_attendance_list.size());
                            StudentAttendanceAdapter studentAttendanceAdapter = new StudentAttendanceAdapter(getActivity(), student_attendance_list);
                            System.out.println(student_attendance_list.size());
                            listView.setAdapter(studentAttendanceAdapter);


                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            System.out.println("This is not good");
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }

                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // Toast.makeText(view.Fee.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                return headers;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                // do s.th.
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


}
```

> How can this issue be Solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this just add your edittext's addTextChangedListener it may help you..

```
editTextEndDate.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
       if(editTextStartDate.getText.toString() != ""){
            getAttendanceDataWithFilter();
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: Most Welcome.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

One:Use a listener like OnFocusChangeListener,when the Edittext lose focus you can refresh date!
Two:Add a TextWatcher on Edittext,when text changed,check it and update date!

Comment: can't i check through  the length of the edittext and then  filter

Comment: Use Regular language to match a Date is useful,but i think it is a little complex